# Getting a $set error even though i am setting it?

Tags: mongodb

```
chats.post('/approveUser', (req, res) => {
  // let regex = new RegExp(req.body.requestId)
  Chat.updateOne(
    { 'requests._id': req.body.requestId },
    { $set: {'approved': true} },
    { upsert: true }
  )
    .then(res => {
      console.log('hi')
      if (!res) {
        res.status(404).send()
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(res)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).send(err)
    })
})
```

Does anyone see why i'm getting an error? It says:

```
errmsg: '\'$set\' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}'
```

req.body.requestId is not undefined. This is the layout of each mongoDB document:

```
{
  "_id":"5cd1f4aceb05c12298779345",
  "title":"test 3",
  "participants":[
    {
      "_id":"5cd1f4aceb05c12298779347",
      "userEmail":"test@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "_id":"5cd1f4aceb05c12298779346",
      "userEmail":"adam2.cole@northumbria.ac.uk"
    }],
    "chatType":"publicGroup",
    "messages":[
      {
        "_id":"5cd254b591a0eb1de4a0863c",
        "text":"hi",
        "from":"test@gmail.com",
        "dateTimeSent":"2019-05-08T04:01:57.732Z"
      },
      {
        "_id":"5cd254b591a0eb1de4a0863b",
        "text":"hi",
        "from":"test@gmail.com",
        "dateTimeSent":"2019-05-08T04:01:57.764Z"
      }
    ],
  "__v":0,
  "requests":[
    {
      "approved":false,
      "_id":"5cd2467891a0eb1de4a08631",
      "userEmail":"test2@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

The intention is to turn `approved` of any `request` to true. I'm failing to see why it won't work. Does anyone else see why?

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried removing the quotation marks from the `$set` around `approved` and it didn't work.

Comment: Try including `{strict: false}` in your query